# Php Function not returning Json Object

Tags: php, laravel-5, twilio-php

Hi I have a function that takes in a phonenumber as a parameter.

in all the scenarios the code displays the echoed message however doesnt return the json what am I missing here?

```
public function ValidateAndSentMessageTo($number){

    if(!$this->MyValidateNumber($number)){
        $this->MyRegister($number);
    }

    $this->MyUpdateValCode($number);
    //TODO::SendMessage
    $this->SendMessageTo($number);

    echo $this->_ValCode;   //THIS IS DISPLAYED on the screen
    return json_encode(['Valcode' => $this->_ValCode]); //THIS IS NOT DISPLAYED ON THE SCREEN
}
```

in case you would like to see send message to function.

```
$AccountSid = "xxxx";
    $AuthToken = "xxx";

    $client = new Twilio\Rest\Client($AccountSid, $AuthToken);

    $client->account->messages->create($number,array(
        'from'=> "+xxxx",
        'body'=>"Your Flare Validation Code: ".$this->_ValCode));
}
```

any help is appreciated and thanks in advance!

Comment: return will not render anything to the screen, it is only for 'returning' the output to another function (which can subsequently `echo` if necessary)

Comment: the return value shall appear in the request result Not in the view

Comment: You also need to show us the code that is calling the `ValidateAndSentMessageTo` function in order to answer this ... or is `ValidateAndSentMessageTo` a controller action? If it is a controller action, try `return response()->json(['Valcode' => $this->_ValCode])`.